# Is it possible to use acritical value from the F distribution with a CI of 95% and obtain the z value with a CI of 99% in the same problem?

Tags: statistical-significance, cumulative-distribution-function, f-distribution

I am studying this article "Variance sensitive adaptive threshold-based PCA method for fault detection with experimental application (Alkaya,2011)" in order to apply the adaptive threshold in one problem. In this article one threshold depends of the value obatined from the F distribution table. And another one depends on the z value obtained from the relation: 1-alpha/2, being alpha the level of significance.

these two thresholds are related later to determine the Tvsa threshold by a set of conditions.
Would it be statistically wrong to use different confidence intervals?

please help Y-Y